# How to solve $xy''+2y'+\lambda^2 \, xy=0$ with the power series method?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

Find all functions $y(x)$ which can be expressed as a convergent power series $y(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^n$ and which satisfy the following differential equation:

$$xy''+2y'+\lambda^2 \, xy=0$$

Comment: What are your thoughts on the matter?

Comment: Working just a little the differential equation could clarify a lot the problem.

Comment: Another observation: are you sure you did not mean this? $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$$ Because, to me, in this case $a^n$ is the $n$-th power of a constant.

Answer (score 0):

Assume $$y(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^n,$$ then 
$$y'(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n n x^{n-1}$$
and
$$y''(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n n (n-1)x^{n-2}$$
substitute to 
$$xy′′+2y′+(λ^2) \, xy=0$$
to get
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n n (n-1)x^{n-1}+2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n n x^{n-1}+(λ^2) \, \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^{n+1}=0$$
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n+1}( n+1) n x^{n}+2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_{n+1} (n+1) x^{n}+(λ^2) \, \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n-1} x^{n}=0$$
$$2 a_{1}  + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(a_{n+1}( n+1) n +2 a_{n+1} (n+1) +(λ^2)  a_{n-1} \right)x^{n}=0$$
$$2 a_{1}  + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(a_{n+1}(2 + 3 n + n^2) +(λ^2)  a_{n-1} \right)x^{n}=0$$
by substituting $x=0$ one get $a_1=0$, we also have that 
$$\left(a_{n+1}(2 + 3 n + n^2) +(λ^2)  a_{n-1} \right)=0,\forall n\ge1$$
so $$
a_{n+1} =-\frac{λ^2}{n^2 + 3 n + 2}  a_{n-1} 
$$
thus $a_{2m-1}=0$ and (prove by yourself) $a_{2m}=\frac{2  \left(-\lambda ^2\right)^m}{ (2 m+1)!}a_{0},$
where $m=1,2,3\dots$.

Finally:
$$y(x)=a_{0}\sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \frac{2  \left(-\lambda ^2\right)^m}{ (2 m+1)!} x^2m,$$