# Find a power series solution to $xy''(x) + 2y'(x) + xy(x) = 1, \quad y(0) = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

> Seek a power series solution to the problem $$xy''(x) + 2y'(x) + xy(x) = 1, \quad  y(0) = 0$$

I'm struggling with the above question. This is my attempt at a solution:

Set $y(x) = \sum_0^{\infty} a_kx^k$.

Then $y'(x) = \sum_1^{\infty} a_k k x^{k-1}$ and $y''(x) = \sum_2^{\infty} a_k k(k-1)x^{k-2}$. Substituting into the equation we get:

$$\begin{align} xy''(x) + 2y'(x) + xy(x) &= 1  \\ x \sum_2^{\infty} a_k k(k-1)x^{k-2} + 2\sum_1^{\infty} a_k k x^{k-1} + x\sum_0^{\infty} a_kx^k &= 1  \end{align}$$

Manipulating the indices to gather everything under the same summation: $$\sum^{\infty}_1 x^k a_k (k^2 +k +1) = 1$$

How do I incorporate the initial condition? I am very confused...

Comment: Note that $(xy)''=xy''+2y'$ so that your equation has a very easy symbolic solution. You could search for previous instances of this task, like in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3292893/finding-the-solution, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1547169/how-to-solve

Comment: The step "manipulating the indices" is not correct. This should make appear some $a_{k+2}$ and $a_{k+1}$ along with the $a_k$ in your last sum.

Answer (score 1):

If I may suggest, do not change the index and write first
$$x\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} k(k-1) a_k x^{k-2}+2\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} k a_kx^{k-1}+x\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_kx^{k}-1=0$$ that is to say
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\big[k(k-1)+2k \big] a_kx^{k-1}+\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_kx^{k+1}-1=0$$ $$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}k(k+1)a_kx^{k-1}+\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a_kx^{k+1}-1=0$$

To make $x^m$, for the first summation you need $k-1=m$ that is to say $k=m+1$ and for the second $k+1=m$ that is to say $k=m-1$. So
$$(m+1)(m+2)a_{m+1}+a_{m-1}=0$$
and you already know that $a_0=0$. Now, work the very first terms.